# Spring Integration Unmarshalling

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-http

I am trying to unmarshal java objects to xml in Spring integration using UnmarshallingTransformer but I am getting an error that the payload is not created.
This is my code :

```
@Bean
    public Marshaller jaxbMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(TargetedClass.class);

        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow posting() {


        try {

            return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                                    
                            ).errorChannel("error.input")
                    )

                    .transform(Transformers.objectToString())

                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression())
                    .transform(httpcallFunc())
                    .transform(new UnmarshallingTransformer((Unmarshaller) jaxbMarshaller()))

                    .get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting this error back.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to create Source for payload type [com.org.model.ClassName]
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "<Map><timestamp>2022-03-18T11:24:26.568+00:00</timestamp><status>500</status><error>Internal Server Error</error><path>/foo</path></Map>"
```

This occurs when I am trying to use the UnmarshallingTransformer.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnmarshallingTransformer` uses a `DomSourceFactory` by default. And its logic is like this:

```
        if (this.alwaysUseSourceFactory) {
            source = this.sourceFactory.createSource(payload);
        }
        else if (payload instanceof String) {
            source = new StringSource((String) payload);
        }
        else if (payload instanceof byte[]) {
            source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) payload));
        }
        else if (payload instanceof File) {
            File file = (File) payload;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            source = new StreamSource(inputStream, file.toURI().toASCIIString());
        }
        else if (payload instanceof Document) {
            source = new DOMSource((Document) payload);
        }
        else if (payload instanceof Source) {
            source = (Source) payload;
        }
        else {
            source = this.sourceFactory.createSource(payload);
        }
```

Since no one condition applies because of the default options and your custom type `com.org.model.ClassName`, it fails to the last `else`. The `DomSourceFactory` has a logic like this:

```
public Source createSource(Object payload) {
    Source source = null;
    if (payload instanceof Document) {
        source = createDomSourceForDocument((Document) payload);
    }
    else if (payload instanceof String) {
        source = createDomSourceForString((String) payload);
    }
    else if (payload instanceof File) {
        source = createDomSourceForFile((File) payload);
    }
    if (source == null) {
        throw new MessagingException("failed to create Source for payload type [" +
                payload.getClass().getName() + "]");
    }
    return source;
}
```

Which also does not satisfy your `com.org.model.ClassName`. Therefore an exception you see in your logs and so.

I'm not sure what is your expectations, but the type you produce from your `httpcallFunc()` is not what would be compatible with the `UnmarshallingTransformer`.